# Error: "Subreport cannot be show".

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, reportingservices-2005

I have a main Report (RDL) with 2 subreports. Sometimes the subreport fails (the reason is not important) but the main report is still rendered, with below text message.

Error: Subreport could not be shown

Is it possible to bubble the subreport error such that the generation of the main report fails or throws an exception. We are using ReportExecutionService API to render the report.

Answer (score 2):

Parse the warning messages, which is returned when you call Render method.

Refer:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/reportexecution2005.warning.aspx